# sorting according to a custom comparator

Tags: sorting, dictionary, vector, clojure

I've got a map looking like this:

```
user> (frequencies "aaabccddddee")
{\a 3, \b 1, \c 2, \d 4, \e 2}
```

And I'd like to have a function that would sort the key/value pairs according to the order each character is appearing in a string I'd pass as an argument.

Something like this:

```
user> (somesort "defgcab" (frequencies "aaabccddddee"))
[[\d 4] [\e 2] [\c 2] [\a 3] [\b 1]]
```

*(in the example above 'f' and 'g' do not appear in the map and they're hence ignored.  It is guaranteed that the string -- "defgcab" in this example -- shall contain every character/key in the map)*

The resulting collection doesn't matter much as long as it is sorted.

I've tried several things but cannot find a way to make this work.

Answer (score 6):

I kinda prefer using `sort-by` to do the sorting logic, and just create a custom comparator for your collection:

```
(defn sorter [coll] (zipmap coll (range)))

(sort-by (comp (sorter "defgcab") key) 
         (frequencies "aaabccddddee"))

;=> ([\d 4] [\e 2] [\c 2] [\a 3] [\b 1])
```

**Edit**: this has the further advantage that you can keep your collection a map if you want, although you have to do a little more work:

```
(defn map-sorter [coll]
  (let [order (zipmap coll (range))]
    (fn [a b]
      (compare (order a) (order b)))))

(into (sorted-map-by (map-sorter "defgcab"))
      (frequencies "aaabccddddee"))

;=> {\d 4, \e 2, \c 2, \a 3, \b 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn somesort [str st] 
    (filter (fn [[k v]] v ) (map (fn [c] [c (get st c)]) str)) )
```

How this works:

- Using map on the "sorting string" for each character in that string get the corresponding key value as a vector from the set
- Using filter, filter out the elements where the value is nil

Comment: oh I see...  Thanks.  Does it means the complexity is O(n^2)?

Comment: @CedricMartin The complexity depends on the lookup in the map. If the map is large, then make sure it's a hash map, then the complexity is linear.

Answer (score 2):

Ankur's solution expressed with `for` , which is maybe a bit easier to read:

```
(defn somesort [str st] 
    (for [c str :let [v  (get st c)] :when v] [c v]))
```

This works assuming the characters in the custom sorting string are unique.

The sorting string is iterated over once, each of its characters is looked up in a map. If you make sure the map passed to the function is a hash map, then this is linear.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `find` which returns `[k v]` with `map` :

```
(let [fs (frequencies "abbccc")]
  (map #(find fs %) "defgcab")
```

Comment: Doesn't this invoke `frequencies` for each letter in the given alphabet?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler, Yes it does. Rafal or Ankur solutions are faster

Comment: Very inefficient indeed! Thank you guys for pointing that out. I was too focused on doing "looking up by value" and being too lazy to wrap it up in a function.

Comment: I made a minor adjustment so that the frequencies are only calculated once.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. It's exactly what I intended. It didn't even occur to me that I could edit.